# PreferenceFragmentからDialogFragmentを表示し画面回転で例外発生

Tags: android, fragment

こんにちは。

AndroidでPreferenceFragmentからDialogFragmentを表示した時の処理について質問させてください。

まず、Android 2.3にも対応するため、以下のライブラリを使用しております。
android-support-v4
android-support-v7-appcompat
android-support-v4-preferencefragment-master

PreferenceFragmentからDialogFragmentを表示し、DialogFragment内のボタン押下で、PreferenceFragmentに通知するようなプログラムです。

このプログラムでDialogFragmentを表示したまま画面回転を行うと、1回回転させたところでダイアログのOKボタンを押すと、以下の例外で落ちます。
PreferenceFragment内のgetResourcesで落ちていることから、DialogFragmentがコールバックしたPreferenceFragmentのリスナは、フラグメント再生成前の古い物だと考えます。

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment PrefFragment{41acf090} not attached to Activity
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:619)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:641)
  at com.example.MyActivity$PrefFragment.onOkClicked(MyActivity.java:349)
  at com.example.MyDialog$1.onClick(MyDialog.java:149)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4300)
  at android.widget.Button.performClick(Button.java:140)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17570)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5158)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

さらに、2回回転させると以下の例外で落ちます。

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: MyDialog{41844c70 #1 dialog} has target not in fragment manager: PrefFragment{418472d0}
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1714)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:524)
  at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1147)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1216)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3753)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:167)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5158)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

setTargetFragment()、getTargetFragment()を使うと、フラグメントの再生成が行われた時でも関連づけが行われるという情報を得て、このプログラムを開発中です。

国内、海外の方々のサイトを見て回ったのですが、同じような事例はあるものの、これといった解決策が見つからず、困っております。

どこに問題があるかおわかりの方、ご教授いただければ幸いです。

MyActivity (PreferenceFragment)

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static PrefFragment mPreference;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preference_layout);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        mPreference = new PrefFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, mPreference).commit();
    }

    public static class PrefFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements MyDialog.OnOkClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);

            // preference.xml内のPreferenceScreenにリスナ登録
            screenPrefParent = getText(R.string.key_menu_search_engine_set);
            PreferenceScreen prefScreen = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference(screenPrefParent);
            prefScreen.setOnPreferenceClickListener(preferenceClickListener);
        }

        private OnPreferenceClickListener preferenceClickListener = new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                // PreferenceScreenがクリックされたのでDialogFragment表示
                String engine = (String) preference.getSummary();
                MyDialog dialog = MyDialog.newInstance(mPreference, engine);  //フラグメントを渡す
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager(); 
                dialog.show(manager, "dialog");
                return true;
            }
        };

        // DialogFragmentのOKボタンが押された
        @Override
        public void onOkClicked(Bundle data) {
            CharSequence screenPrefParent = getText(R.string.key_menu_search_engine_set);
            PreferenceScreen prefScreen = (PreferenceScreen) this.findPreference(screenPrefParent);
            String engine = data.getString("ENGINE");
            prefScreen.setSummary(engine);
        }

    };
}
```

MyDialog (DialogFragment)

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public interface OnOkClickListener {
        public void onOkClicked(Bundle data);
    }

    public static MyDialog newInstance(Fragment fragment, String engine) {
        MyDialog instance = new MyDialog();
        instance.setTargetFragment(fragment, 0); // ターゲットフラグメントをここで保存
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();            // 引数を保存
        bundle.putString("ENGINE", engine);
        instance.setArguments(bundle);
        return instance;
    }

    public MyDialog() {
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.MyDialogTheme);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.search_engine_set_dialog);

        EditText edit = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editSearchEngine);
        String text = getArguments().getString("ENGINE");
        edit.setText(text);
        // OKボタンにリスナ登録
        Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);
        button.setOnClickListener(okButtonClickListener);
        return dialog;
    }

    private View.OnClickListener okButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dialog dialog = getDialog();
            if (dialog != null) {
                try {
                    // ターゲットフラグメントのリスナを取得
                    OnOkClickListener listener = (OnOkClickListener) getTargetFragment();
                    // リスナ呼び出し
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    EditText edit = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editSearchEngine);
                    bundle.putString("ENGINE", edit.getText().toString());
                    listener.onOkClicked(bundle);
                } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                }
            }
            dismiss();
        }

    };
}
```

以上よろしくお願いします。

---

**EDIT 1**

自分流に解決策を作ってみたので、書いてみます。

そもそも、今回の事例でsetTargetFragment()、getTargetFragment()を行うのは、DialogFragmentからPreferenceFragmentをコールバックするためでした。

しかし、setTargetFragment()、getTargetFragment()がうまく働いてくれません。setTargetFragment()でフラグメントをセットすると、画面2回回転で

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: MyDialog{41844c70 #1 dialog} has target not in fragment manager: PrefFragment{418472d0}
```

という例外で落ちてしまう始末。これは、setTargetFragment()されたフラグメントの関連づけを行おうとして、失敗しているものと思われます。

そこで、setTargetFragment()、getTargetFragment()を使わずに、自前のフラグメント管理クラスを作ってみました。

FragmentData (フラグメント1つを格納するクラス)

```
public class FragmentData {

    public String name;         // フラグメントの名前
    public Fragment fragment;   // フラグメント

    public FragmentData(String name, Fragment fragment) {
        this.name = name;
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

}
```

FragmentDataList (フラグメントを管理するクラス)

```
class FragmentDataList {

    // static なのが重要
    private static ArrayList<FragmentData> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<FragmentData>();

    // フラグメントを名前付きで記憶する
    static void add(String name, Fragment fragment) {
        remove(name);  // すでに同じ名前の登録があれば消す
        FragmentData data = new FragmentData(name, fragment);
        mFragmentList.add(data);
    }

    // 指定された名前のフラグメントの登録を消す
    static void remove(String name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mFragmentList.size(); i++ ) {
            FragmentData data = mFragmentList.get(i);
            if (data.name.equals(name)) {
                mFragmentList.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // 指定された名前のフラグメントを得る
    static Fragment get(String name) {
        Fragment ret = null;
        for (FragmentData data : mFragmentList) {
            if (data.name.equals(name)) {
                ret = data.fragment;
                break;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

MyActivity (PreferenceFragment)

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // ★★フラグメントに名前をつける
    private static final String FRAGMENT_NAME = "SETTING";

    private static PrefFragment mPreference;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           ...途中省略...
    }

    public static class PrefFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements MyDialog.OnOkClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);

            // ★★ここでフラグメントを登録する
            FragmentDataList.add(FRAGMENT_NAME, this);
                   ...途中省略...
        }

        private OnPreferenceClickListener preferenceClickListener = new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                // PreferenceScreenがクリックされたのでDialogFragment表示
                String engine = (String) preference.getSummary();
                MyDialog dialog = MyDialog.newInstance(FRAGMENT_NAME, engine);  // ★★DialogFragmentにこのフラグメントの名前を渡す
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager(); 
                dialog.show(manager, "dialog");
                return true;
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            // ★★ここでフラグメントの登録解除
            FragmentDataList.remove(FRAGMENT_NAME);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            // ★★ここでフラグメントを再登録
            FragmentDataList.add(FRAGMENT_NAME, this);
        }
    };
}
```

MyDialog (DialogFragment)

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public interface OnOkClickListener {
        public void onOkClicked(Bundle data);
    }

    public static MyDialog newInstance(String targetFragmentName, String engine) {
        MyDialog instance = new MyDialog();
// ★★setTargetFragment()はやめる
//      instance.setTargetFragment(fragment, 0); // ターゲットフラグメントをここで保存
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();            // 引数を保存
        bundle.putString("TARGET", targetFragmentName);  // ★★ターゲットフラグメントの名前を保存
        bundle.putString("ENGINE", engine);
        instance.setArguments(bundle);
        return instance;
    }

    public MyDialog() {
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                   ...途中省略...
    }

    private View.OnClickListener okButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dialog dialog = getDialog();
            if (dialog != null) {
                try {
                    // ターゲットフラグメントのリスナを取得
// ★★getTargetFragment()はやめる
//                  OnOkClickListener listener = (OnOkClickListener) getTargetFragment();

                    // ★★ターゲットフラグメントの名前を元に、フラグメントを得てリスナを取得
                    String targetFragmentName = getArguments().getString("TARGET")
                    Fragment targetFragment = FragmentDataList.get(targetFragmentName);
                    OnOkButtonClickListener listener = (OnOkButtonClickListener) targetFragment; 

                    // リスナ呼び出し
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    EditText edit = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editSearchEngine);
                    bundle.putString("ENGINE", edit.getText().toString());
                    listener.onOkClicked(bundle);
                } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                }
            }
            dismiss();
        }

    };
}
```

★★を付けたところが、改変のポイントです。
どうやら、うまく動いているようです。

ただ、PreferenceFragmentからDialogFragmentを表示すると、DialogFragmentを閉じた後、DialogFragmentを開いた回数+1回「戻る」ボタンを押さないと、PreferenceFragmentが終わってくれません。
新たな問題が起こりました。

---

**EDIT 2**

> ただ、PreferenceFragmentからDialogFragmentを表示すると、DialogFragmentを閉じた後、DialogFragmentを開いた回数+1回「戻る」ボタンを押さないと、PreferenceFragmentが終わってくれません。
>   新たな問題が起こりました。

と書きましたが、試行錯誤の段階で、DialogFragmentを作成する時に余計な処理を追加してしまっていたのが原因でした。

MyActivity (PreferenceFragment)

```
           ...途中省略...
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

    // ★★ここから
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
    // ★★ここまでが試行錯誤の段階で追加した部分

    // PreferenceScreenがクリックされたのでDialogFragment表示
    String engine = (String) preference.getSummary();
    MyDialog dialog = MyDialog.newInstance(FRAGMENT_NAME, engine);
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager(); 
    dialog.show(manager, "dialog");
```

上記の★★で囲まれた余計な部分を取り除いたら、「戻る」問題も解決しました。

---

**EDIT 3**

onResumeでフラグメントを登録しているので、onCreateでのフラグメントの登録は余分でした。
あと、リストの操作は、きちんと排他制御した方がいいですね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 回転させた後OKを押すと落ちる

> 1回回転させたところでダイアログのOKボタンを押すと、以下の例外で落ちます。

この原因は

```
private static PrefFragment mPreference;
```

でアウタークラスの`Activity`が保持した`Fragment`をダイアログに持たせているためです。

```
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            Log.d("debug", "hello!");
            // PreferenceScreenがクリックされたのでDialogFragment表示
            String engine = (String) preference.getSummary();
            MyDialog dialog = MyDialog.newInstance(PrefFragment.this, engine);  //フラグメントを渡す
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
            return true;
        }
```

`PrefFragment.this`を渡すようにすれば解決します。

しかしこれだけでは再生成された`PrefFragment`へコールバックされません。

#### setTargetFragment()で設定したフラグメントの関連付けを維持したい

> これは、setTargetFragment()されたフラグメントの関連づけを行おうとして、失敗しているものと思われます。

これがなぜかというと、`FragmentActivity`が`Fragment`の状態を復元しようとしているのと、`onCreate()`で毎回`Fragment`を作り直す処理が競合しているためです。

```
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, new PrefFragment()).commit();
    }
```

のように条件を設定して、初回だけ`PrefFragment`を生成するようにすれば、`getTargetFragment()`が正しく機能します。

Comment: この辺の深遠に関して興味がありましたら、`setTargetFragment()/getTargetFragment()`がどう実装されており、`FragmentManager`が現在の`Fragment`の状態をどう保存し、また関連付けを復元させているのか…というような説明を探すといいかもしれません。

Comment: quesera2さん、回答ありがとうございます。問題解決を急ぐあまり、根本の所の究明が不十分でした。setTargetFragment()、getTargetFragment()については、Androidのソースなども目を通したのですが、結局詳しいところは分からずじまいでおりました。ご指摘を踏まえて、今一度処理を見直してみたいと思います。ウエブサイトなどでは、私が最初に書いたような処理手順が説明されている例が多いと思います。

Comment: さっそくソースを変更して動作を試してみました。何日も悩んでいたことが嘘のように正常に動作するようになりました。どうもありがとうございます。